# How to get rid of additional folder named "netstandardxx" in .NET standard class library project output path in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, class-library, .net-standard, project-template, project-properties

I created a project in VS2017 using .NET Standard Class Library Project Template. The problem is when I wanted to change the project output path to some arbitrary folder, it appends to my selected path, another folder named "netstandardxx" (in which xx refers to the version of .net standard I'm using).
No matter how many times I try to change the output path and get rid of the additional unwanted folder, it comes back again.

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I googled my problem and found the answer which worked for me and thought may be it is a good idea to post a question and its answer, just in order to help other folks:
In order to disable this default behavior you can set the following property in .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: thanks, more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2022